# Create object dynamically after get() from server

Tags: angular, object, undefined

Is there a way to create `itemsAndPageableInfo` object dynamically and then for example print at the view `itemsAndPageableInfo.content`?

```
  itemsAndPageableInfo : {};      

    this.itemService.getItems(0, 2)
              .subscribe(res => {
                this.itemsAndPageableInfo = res.json();
                this.items = res.json().content;
              });
```

I am trying to do `<tr *ngFor="let item of itemsAndPageableInfo.content; let i = index">` but I get an error that `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

Comment: Use safe operator: `<tr *ngFor="let item of itemsAndPageableInfo?.content; let i = index">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `itemsAndPageableInfo` to an empty iterable or not show the `<tr>` until it has loaded.

The reason for this is `itemsAndPageableInfo` is populated asynchronously and the data shows up after the elements have been loaded in the DOM resulting in a null reference.